# NoSuchMethodError:registerAutoProxyCreatorIfNecessary(ParserContext;Object;) exception with Spring config with Spring 4.0

Tags: spring-3, spring-4

I am getting following exception since I upgraded to Spring 4.0 from Spring 3.0. The project compiles fine but when once it is deployed to tomcat and instantiated theses errors start to come across,

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.aop.config.AopNamespaceUtils.registerAutoProxyCreatorIfNecessary(Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/xml/ParserContext;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:413)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:216)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:187)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:540)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:454)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:624)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:543)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1266)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1080)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5027)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:618)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:963)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1600)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.aop.config.AopNamespaceUtils.registerAutoProxyCreatorIfNecessary(Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/xml/ParserContext;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at org.springframework.transaction.config.AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.parseInternal(AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.java:54)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.AbstractBeanDefinitionParser.parse(AbstractBeanDefinitionParser.java:60)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:74)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1424)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1414)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:141)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:110)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391)
    ... 33 more
May 13, 2014 7:11:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.aop.config.AopNamespaceUtils.registerAutoProxyCreatorIfNecessary(Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/xml/ParserContext;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:413)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:216)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:187)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:540)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:454)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:624)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:543)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1266)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1080)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5027)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.aop.config.AopNamespaceUtils.registerAutoProxyCreatorIfNecessary(Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/xml/ParserContext;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at org.springframework.transaction.config.AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.parseInternal(AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.java:54)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.AbstractBeanDefinitionParser.parse(AbstractBeanDefinitionParser.java:60)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:74)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1424)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1414)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:141)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:110)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391)
    ... 33 more

May 13, 2014 7:11:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet /lcms threw load() exception
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.aop.config.AopNamespaceUtils.registerAutoProxyCreatorIfNecessary(Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/xml/ParserContext;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at org.springframework.transaction.config.AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.parseInternal(AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.java:54)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.AbstractBeanDefinitionParser.parse(AbstractBeanDefinitionParser.java:60)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:74)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1424)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1414)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:141)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:110)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:216)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:187)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:540)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:454)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:624)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:543)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
```

Here is my POM file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>lcms</groupId>
  <artifactId>lcms.web</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>lcms.web</name>

<!--    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.softech.ls360.lcms</groupId>
  <artifactId>contentbuilder</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>lcms Maven Webapp</name>
  -->

  <repositories>
       <repository>
            <id>360mavenserver</id>
            <name>360mavenserver-releases</name>
            <url>xxxxxxxxxxx/lcmsdaomodel/lcms.dao.model/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
          <properties>
            <spring.version>4.0.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
            <spring.security.version>3.1.4.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
          </properties>
          <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                  <groupId>junit</groupId>
                  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                  <version>3.8.1</version>
                  <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                    <version>${spring.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                    <version>${spring.version}</version>
                </dependency> 
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                    <version>${spring.version}</version>
                </dependency> 
                    <!-- Spring Security -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
                    <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
                    <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
                </dependency> 
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
                    <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
                </dependency>
<!--                <dependency> -->
<!--                    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId> -->
<!--                    <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId> -->
<!--                    <version>${spring.security.version}</version> -->
<!--                </dependency> -->
<!--                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                    <version>${spring.version}</version>
                </dependency>
-->             
                <dependency>
                  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                  <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                  <version>${spring.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                      <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
                      <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
                      <version>1.7</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                      <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
                      <artifactId>velocity-tools</artifactId>
                      <version>2.0</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                  <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
                  <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
                  <version>1.1.2</version>
                </dependency>   
                <dependency>
                  <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
                  <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
                  <version>20030825.184428</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                  <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
                  <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
                  <version>20030825.183949</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
                    <version>1.3.1</version>
                </dependency>   
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
                    <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
                </dependency>
                 <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
                    <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1</version>
                  </dependency>                   
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                    <version>1.6.1</version>
                </dependency>
                <!-- concrete Log4J Implementation for SLF4J API-->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                    <version>1.6.1</version>
                </dependency>       
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.1</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2</version>
                </dependency>   
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                    <version>1.6.11</version>
                </dependency>        
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                    <version>1.6.11</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>antlr</groupId>
                    <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
                    <version>2.7.7</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>lcmsdaomodel</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lcms.dao.model</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1.0</version>
                </dependency>
          </dependencies>

     <build>
       <finalName>lcms</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>D:\Java\tomcat7\webapps\</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>       
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
     </build>
</project>
```

and My Servlet dispatcher file

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"    


    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd       
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd        
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd       
        ">
  <context:annotation-config />
  <context:component-scan base-package="com.softech.ls360.lcms.contentbuilder" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping">
    </bean>
    <bean id="velocityConfig"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityConfigurer">
        <property name="resourceLoaderPath" value="/WEB-INF/vm/"/>
        <property name="velocityProperties">
         <props>
           <prop key="input.encoding">UTF-8</prop>
           <prop key="output.encoding">UTF-8</prop>
         </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityViewResolver">
        <property name="cache" value="false" />
        <property name="prefix" value="" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".vm" />
        <property name="exposeSpringMacroHelpers" value="true" />
        <property name="exposeRequestAttributes" value="true" />
        <property name="allowRequestOverride" value="true" />
        <property name="exposeSessionAttributes" value="true" />
        <property name="allowSessionOverride" value="true" />
        <property name="toolboxConfigLocation" value="/WEB-INF/toolbox.xml" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
        p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />
     <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close"
        p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
        p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}"
        p:password="${jdbc.password}" />

        <bean id="entityManagerFactory" 
            class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" 
            p:jpaVendorAdapter-ref="jpaAdapter">

            <property name="dataSource">
                <ref bean="dataSource" />
            </property>
            <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
                <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver" />
            </property>

        </bean>

        <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
            <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="jpaAdapter"
            class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"
            p:showSql="true">
        </bean>

        <!-- Aspect -->
        <bean id="logAspect" class="com.softech.ls360.lcms.contentbuilder.utils.LoggingAspect" />

       <bean id="CourseService" class="com.softech.ls360.lcms.contentbuilder.service.impl.CourseServiceImpl">     
          <property name="courseDAO" ref="courseDAO" />
        </bean>
          <bean name="courseDAO" class="com.softech.ls360.lcms.contentbuilder.dao.impl.CourseDAOImpl" />
        <!--  <bean id="vu360UserServiceImpl" class="com.softech.ls360.lcms.contentbuilder.service.impl.VU360UserServiceImpl">
        </bean> 
        -->
        <bean id="messageSource"
              class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
              <property name="basename" value="classpath:locale/branding" />
              <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
        </bean>
        <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
               class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
               <property name="paramName" value="lang"/>
           </bean>    
        <bean id="localeResolver"
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
            <property name="defaultLocale" value="en_US"/>
        </bean>
        <bean id="themeSource"
            class="org.springframework.ui.context.support.ResourceBundleThemeSource">
                <property name="basenamePrefix" value="theme.theme-" />
        </bean> 
        <!-- Theme Change Interceptor and Resolver definition -->
        <bean id="themeChangeInterceptor"
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.ThemeChangeInterceptor">
            <property name="paramName" value="theme" />
        </bean>
        <bean id="themeResolver"
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.CookieThemeResolver">
            <property name="defaultThemeName" value="default" />
        </bean>
        <bean id="handlerMapping"
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
            <property name="interceptors">
                <list>
                    <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
                    <ref bean="themeChangeInterceptor" />
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>

        <tx:annotation-driven />

        <!-- Setting up static resources --> 
        <mvc:annotation-driven />
            <mvc:resources mapping="/theme/**" location="/theme/" />
            <mvc:resources mapping="/javascript/**" location="/javascript/" />
        <mvc:interceptors>
           <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
               <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
           </bean>
            <bean 
                class="org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.ThemeChangeInterceptor">
                <property name="paramName" value="theme" />
            </bean>
        </mvc:interceptors>



        <!-- ========================= HIBERNATE DEFINITIONS ======================================== -->
        <!-- Local DataSource that works in any environment -->
        <!-- Note that DriverManagerDataSource does not pool; it is not intended for production -->
        <!-- See JPetStore for an example of using Commons DBCP BasicDataSource as alternative -->
        <!-- See Image Database for an example of using C3P0 ComboPooledDataSource  as alternative -->

        <import resource="jpa-hibernate-config.xml" />

</beans>
```

Comment: What do you have under WEB-INF/lib?